# Chart multiple sequential series from a single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I'd like to produce a chart with multiple sequential time series drawn from a single column, at specific points of my choosing. I can easily do what I want if I split the data into multiple columns, but I really don't want to do that:

[image: example chart]

If I try to define multiple "series" in the chart editor, each series loses its attached date range and they all show up stacked, rather than one after the other. I'm hoping there's a way to do this without splitting the data into columns!

[image]

Alternatively, is there any other way in google sheets to add piecewise linear trendlines to a single series? The only reason I need to break this up is to get the piecewise trendlines...

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try SPARKLINE? - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289?hl=en

Comment: @player0 Thanks, but I don't think that helps produce a full-size chart with multiple trendlines? If I'm somehow missing it, maybe you could try to explain how it might be applicable to my use case?

Comment: It's rare to find someone with the precise same problem, but this is it for me. Creating multiple columns is going to be so ugly and a bunch of unnecessary busy work.